# Signalr unable to connect the remote server

Tags: c#, exception, console, signalr

So, I installed signalr library and everything work wonderful except remote connection.
My client easily has connected to the server locally but when i try to connect remotely i get the next error: **unable to connect the remote server.**

> Firewall if off

**StartUp.cs**

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(PushNotifier.StartUp))]
namespace PushNotifier
{
 public class StartUp
 {
  public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
  {      
   appBuilder.Map("/signalr", map =>
    {
     var hubConfiguration = new HubConfiguration
      {
       EnableDetailedErrors = true,
      };
     map.UseCors(CorsOptions.AllowAll);
     map.RunSignalR(hubConfiguration);
    });
  }
 }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
  public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
   try
   {
    using (WebApp.Start("http://*:8734"))
    {
     while (true)
     {
      var pressedKey = Console.ReadKey(true).Key;

      switch (pressedKey)
      {
       case ConsoleKey.P:
        {
         var hubEntity = new HubEntity();
         hubEntity.SendNotification("hidden", JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VersionEntity>(FileHelper.OpenFile(filePath)).Version);           
        }
        break;

       case ConsoleKey.Escape:
        return;
      }
     }
    }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "|" + ex.StackTrace);
   }
  }
```

**Client.cs**

```
 var connection = new HubConnection("http://10.0.0.18:8734/signalr");

   var hubProxy = connection.CreateHubProxy("HubEntity");

   hubProxy.On<string, string>("addMessage", (message, version) =>
    {
     try
     {
      Console.WriteLine("Connected");
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
     }
    });

   try
   {
    await connection.Start();
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, string.Empty, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    Application.Current.Shutdown();
   }
```

Comment: what happens when you visit http://10.0.0.18:8734/signalr in the browser?

Comment: Protocol error: Unknown transport.

Comment: That problem appear only if i has connected from another pc in the same network.

Comment: I wonder if it is work specifying the transport method: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/hubs-api-guide-net-client await hubConnection.Start(new LongPollingTransport());

Comment: Yep, i tried to initialize LongPollingTransport but no effect. I get the same error.

Comment: Can you give the whole of the stack trace?

Comment: StackTrace screenshot: http://prntscr.com/4c1kwt. 
Here is exception message: "Невозможно соединиться с удаленным сервером" = "Unable to connect the remote server".

Comment: What version of Newtonsoft.Json are you using?

Comment: Json.NET: http://prntscr.com/4c2ad1
SignalR: http://prntscr.com/4c2alh

Comment: I tried to run server side on webserver (IIS) and has made PersistentConnection.
My web page is opened OK from webbrowser not on localhost, I open from another pc on the same netowrk 10.0.0.18. SignalR connection have the same error describeb above. "Unable to connect the remote server"

Comment: Can you try a different port?

Answer (score 3):

I have recently helped another user who followed a similar or the same example on the web, the reason I say that, is because the code is very similar and the methods are pretty much the same.

One problem that I found that came up when attempting the connection when the server is deployed remotely. Was simply this,

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://10.0.0.18:8734/signalr");
```

was simply changed to

```
var connection = new HubConnection("http://10.0.0.18:8734/");
```

the next part of the puzzle may be the ports, however based on the fact that when you browse to the address you get the unknown transport error, which is good in this case, so ports are open and communication is working.

Another common problem is the actual hub name, a few people get the case wrong, however for us to check this, you would need to provide us with the hub implementation, or you can simply try read up about how the name and in some instances methods require case changing in signalr clients.

another problem lies when using 
    await connection.Start();

I cannot see your function that is containing this code, but if it is not marked async, the above call will run synchronously and will create a few problems, this only really becomes visible when the client and server are on separate machines, when the a delay starts coming into play. To eliminate this, I suggest trying

```
hubConnection.Start().Wait();
```

further to help, it is hard to determine what you are doing next, but I will assume that you have not gone past the connection point, which is why you did not place the rest of your code.

I am just for reference going to place code that I know to be working against a similar example, the code is for a console version of the example.

```
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting client  http://10.0.0.18:8734/");

        var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://10.0.0.18:8734/");
        //hubConnection.TraceLevel = TraceLevels.All;
        //hubConnection.TraceWriter = Console.Out;
        IHubProxy myHubProxy = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");

        myHubProxy.On<string, string>("addMessage", (name, message) => Console.Write("Recieved addMessage: " + name + ": " + message + "\n"));
        myHubProxy.On("heartbeat", () => Console.Write("Recieved heartbeat \n"));
        myHubProxy.On<HelloModel>("sendHelloObject", hello => Console.Write("Recieved sendHelloObject {0}, {1} \n", hello.Molly, hello.Age));

        hubConnection.Start().Wait();

        while (true)
        {
            string key = Console.ReadLine();
            if (key.ToUpper() == "W")
            {
                myHubProxy.Invoke("addMessage", "client message", " sent from console client").ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("!!! There was an error opening the connection:{0} \n", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
                    }

                }).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Client Sending addMessage to server\n");
            }
            if (key.ToUpper() == "E")
            {
                myHubProxy.Invoke("Heartbeat").ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection:{0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
                    }

                }).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("client heartbeat sent to server\n");
            }
            if (key.ToUpper() == "R")
            {
                HelloModel hello = new HelloModel { Age = 10, Molly = "clientMessage" };
                myHubProxy.Invoke<HelloModel>("SendHelloObject", hello).ContinueWith(task =>
                {
                    if (task.IsFaulted)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("There was an error opening the connection:{0}", task.Exception.GetBaseException());
                    }

                }).Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("client sendHelloObject sent to server\n");
            }
            if (key.ToUpper() == "C")
            {
                break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I am that same user that added bounty because no one was giving answer on this